# Other processes hang after MPI_Sendrecv

Tags: c++, openmpi

I think using `MPI_Sendrecv`

```
MPI_Sendrecv(&ballPos, 2, MPI_INT, FIELD, NEW_BALL_POS_TAG, &ballPos, 2, MPI_INT, winner, NEW_BALL_POS_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
```

But I noticed only the root (recieving party continues to run?). Having `cout` before and after Sendrecv produces:

```
0 b4 sendrecv
2 b4 sendrecv
4 b4 sendrecv
1 b4 sendrecv
3 b4 sendrecv
5 b4 sendrecv
0 after sendrecv
```

All processes OK before sendrecv, but only root unblocks afterwards.

**[Full source](https://gist.github.com/4039617): see line 147**

**UPDATE**

The result should be something similar to below

```
if (rank == winner) {
    ballPos[0] = rand() % 128;
    ballPos[1] = rand() % 64;
    cout << "new ball pos: " << ballPos[0] << " " << ballPos[1] << endl;
    MPI_Send(&ballPos, 2, MPI_INT, FIELD, NEW_BALL_POS_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
} else if (rank == FIELD) {
    MPI_Recv(&ballPos, 2, MPI_INT, winner, NEW_BALL_POS_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of sends posted should be equal to the number of receives posted. In you case all ranks are sending to rank `FIELD` and receiving from rank `winner`, including `FIELD` and `winner`:

```
Rank       Sends to  Receives from
----------------------------------
0 (FIELD)  FIELD     winner
1          FIELD     winner
2          FIELD     winner
...        ...       ...
winner     FIELD     winner
...        ...       ...
numprocs-1 FIELD     winner
```

(such tables could be very useful sometimes)

Hence `FIELD` should receive `numprocs` messages but it only executes `MPI_Sendrecv` once and hence `numprocs-1` calls to `MPI_Sendrecv` would not be able to complete their sends. The same goes for `winner`. It should send `numprocs` message but as it only executes `MPI_Sendrecv` once, only one message is sent and hence `numprocs-1` calls to `MPI_Sendrecv` would not be able to complete their receives.

There is also another error. The MPI standard requires that the send and the receive buffers be disjoint (i.e. they should not overlap), which is not the case with your code. Your send and receive buffers not only overlap but they are one and the same buffer. If you want to perform the swap in the same buffer, MPI provides the `MPI_Sendrecv_replace` operation.

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve with this `MPI_Sendrecv` statement but I strongly suspect that you need to put it inside an `if` statement.

Comment: I updated the qn with what I expected to happen (Separate Send and Recv calls). Perhaps you could suggest what a corresponding `Sendrecv` call be like?

Comment: @JiewMeng Well, you don't need to perform send-receive. Your original code with separate send and receive should work fine (also see [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13307056/1374437) for why your presumption that it doesn't work is wrong).

Comment: I actually thought if I could shorten that separate send/recv code into 1 sendrecv it would be better. Or its also nice to know the equivalent. I was thinking if I can program in separate send/recv I should be able to use 1 sendrecv too?

Comment: Send-receive is a bidreictional operation. Neither `winner` is receiving, nor `FIELD` is sending data in this case. You can use send-receive but you have to specify `MPI_PROC_NULL` as source rank in `winner` and `MPI_PROC_NULL` as destination rank in `FIELD` which would be an awkward misuse of send-receive _and_ you would still have two different send-receive calls within an `if-then-else` statement. So, just stick to the separate send and receive code - this is how MPI point-to-point calls are supposed to be used.